# GooglePlaces API Error: REQUEST_DENIED on iOS Application

Tags: ios, google-api, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

I have an API key

[image]

When I click on the API details page, I already configure the Application/API restriction

**Application**

[image]

*I restricted to only iOS from my identifier.*

**API**

[image]

I also already getting my bill information in place.

I'm NOT sure why I still getting this error

> GooglePlaces API Error: REQUEST_DENIED

## Result

[image]

Can someone please sheds some light on this ?

I'm clueless now.

Comment: Are you using the iOS SDK or are you making HTTP calls in the app?

Comment: Does it work without restrictions?